# Conversations User List in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a chat system using php,mysql and ajax. But i need help from you about a topic.

In short, I will try to tell you how I try to do it.

I have created one table from database the name is **`chat_conversations`** and table rows are

```
  `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_text` varchar(5000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `message_created_time` varchar(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1524910573',
  `seen` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `message_type` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_ip` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
```

The above table shows how to display messages. When people send messages to each other, the data will come out like this.

[image]

and the above rows will be different when other users join.So far, everything is very nice.

The question I want to ask is: think you are the one with user id 2. And you wanted to see a list of all the people you were chatting with. How did you do that. What I meant to say was that I did not understand how I would uncover it. Because you will have more than one message with `to_user_id` `3` or other `to_user_id` `(4,2,9,12,45, ... ext.)`

How can I unearth the list of chat contacts. How do I write a query.

```
public function ChatUserList($logedInUserID){
    $logedInUserID = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $logedInUserID);
    $ChatUserList = mysqli_query($this->db," how do i write a sql query WHERE from_user_id = '$logedInUserID' ") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ChatUserList)) {
        // Store the result into array
        $data[]=$row;
     }
     if(!empty($data)) {
        // Store the result into array
        return $data;
     }  
}
```

Please look at the screenshot for what i want to show exactly:

[image]

Comment: I would stick to existing chat systems instead of coding your own one. If you still want to do i from the scratch, here is a good tutorial https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/3213/post/1-Tutorial-on-Creating-an-AJAX-based-Chat-system-in-PHP.html

Comment: @AlexOdenthal he wants a query, he does not want an instance made. it also does not provide much solution with the sample question on the link you give.

Comment: that's why I added a comment. and not an answer...

Comment: Incidentally, it's amazingly unlikely that from_user_id would be NULL

Comment: @Strawberry It is NULL, i see it is NULL . I don't understand what you are saying exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(message_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,from_user_id int NOT NULL 
,to_user_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (from_user_id,to_user_id) VALUES
(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(2,5),(7,2),(6,4),(1,6),(2,5),(5,2),(5,2);

SELECT DISTINCT from_user_id chats FROM my_table WHERE to_user_id = 2
UNION
SELECT to_user_id FROM my_table WHERE from_user_id = 2;

+-------+
| chats |
+-------+
|     3 |
|     7 |
|     5 |
|     1 |
+-------+
```

Edit:

From the comments below, it seems like you might be after something like this (untested)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT from_user_id chats
     , type 'from_user' 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE to_user_id = 2
UNION
SELECT to_user_id
     , 'to_user' 
  FROM my_table 
 WHERE from_user_id = 2;
```

Comment: Can you exaplain me please i don't understand how can i print your query within foreach

Comment: What is different then Ebski answer . Ebski answer is giving me correct result but i can not get any result with your query. Can you explain me how your query working, please.

Comment: I am checking your answer but i can not understand can you make it a bit more detailed for me  please ?

Comment: i have tryed your query like this can you check it for me please: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16df60/3

Comment: It is hard to understand for me now, Can you please check this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba894a/4

Comment: but i am getting undefined index `to_user_id` error. I have commented in this sqlfiddle please check it for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba894a/8 . I did everyting like you.

Comment: I am also using your query. Just printing problem did you see the comments from this fiddle ?http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba894a/8

Comment: Oww, i know that Dear, i just want to tell you with comment from there. I know i can not do it on there, i just want to show you the problem section in that fiddle. Also I got all php code into / ** /.

Comment: problem is in a foreach loop i can not call to_user_id and from_user_id with this query

Comment: In short, I want to print the `to_user_id` and `from_user_id` using your query. Is it possible, and how ?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. I'm sorry to bother you. I'm so excited when I learn something new. Thank you again very much.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would be able to write something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.to_user_id, u.name FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = m.to_user_id
WHERE m.from_user_id = '$logedInUserID'.
```

That should give a list of all user ids where conversations exists.

Comment: This will only give you a list of users where you have sent messages to them, not one where they have sent messages to you

Comment: I from is 2 it would return 3, and if from is 3 it would return 2

Comment: But i want to result just conversations user list, not message list.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you want then. What you are getting here is a list of every userid that the $logedInUserID has every sent a message to. By combined the two ids, you will have a list of pairs of all conversations the user is part of

Comment: Yes you are right your query giving this. I want to print the list of people I talked to. not the messages.

Comment: Please look at this screenshot. https://image.prntscr.com/image/fCz8fa24RWyAoOXwRXfqFw.png

Comment: I updated the query. That will give you the name of the person as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, can we show last message with this query. I have check it it is not showing last message.